# postgresql – No crypt function on Debian stretch

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgresql-9.6, crypt, debian-stretch

I have PostgreSQL 9.6 installation on my Debian Stretch (9). When I want to use `crypt()` or `gen_salt()` functions, it says:

```
ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select gen_salt('bf', 8)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I get these functions working?

---

[Installed postgresql packages](https://pastebin.com/YEjgWkBF)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to enable it using SQL:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
```

You have to do it on each database that uses [pgcrypto functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgcrypto.html).

Comment: You can add the "if not exists" parameter to avoid === ERROR: extension "pgcrypto" already exists === like that: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto.